# Change i3-sensible-terminal

Tags: i3

I've spent some time searching whether it's possible to change i3-sensible-terminal, for me it's from urxvt to Alacritty. Everyone suggests to put this keybinding in i3 config: `bindsym $mod+Return exec alacritty`. But that's only partial solution, since it doesn't work when system is trying to open some file in terminal automatically. For example when i3wm displays issue in configuration file, and you want to edit that, it automatically opens in in urxvt.

So, I'm looking for some way, how to "really" change i3-sensible-terminal.

Thanks.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please delete this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I could't find solution how to change that, but what worked for me was that I removed urxvt from my system, though it was little tricky (official package name is rxvt-unicode).

Answer (score 0):

One solution I've found is to modify `/usr/bin/i3-sensible-terminal`, and change the order of the terminals.
So for example, by default the file is something like:

```
for terminal in "$TERMINAL" x-terminal-emulator urxvt (etc etc) alacritty (etc etc)
```

You could modify it so that `alacritty` appears in the list before `urxvt`, and is therefore loaded first:

```
for terminal in "$TERMINAL" alacritty x-terminal-emulator urxvt (etc etc)
```

Alternatively, you should be able to modify the line:

```
exec "$terminal" "$@"
```

to be something like:

```
exec alacritty
```

You can also put other options there aswell, for example, mine is:

```
exec "$terminal" "$@" -rv -e bash -l
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the default terminal emulator for i3-sensible-terminal, you can use the `update-alternatives` command.

```
sudo update-alternatives --set x-terminal-emulator /usr/bin/alacritty
```

This sets Alacritty as the default terminal emulator for the system. Now, i3-sensible-terminal should use Alacritty whenever it is called, even in situations where the system automatically opens a terminal.

Comment: it says "alternative not registered, not setting"